# Vapor parameter decoding hangs up HTTP request

Tags: swift, http, docker, digital-ocean, vapor

i have one weird problem. I'm running vapor inside docker on a digital ocean machine.
All my requests are working as expected except of PATCH and DELETE requests.

In the following code `patch enter` will be logged but not `parameter decode`.
The HTTP request appears to run forever and other requests in parallel are not possible

```
func patch(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Manufacturer> {
    let logger = try req.make(Logger.self)
    logger.info("patch enter")
    return try req.parameters.next(Manufacturer.self).flatMap { manufacturer in
        logger.info("parameter decode")
        return try req.content.decode(Manufacturer.self).flatMap { patchManufacturer in
            logger.info("content decode")
            manufacturer.name = patchManufacturer.name
            return manufacturer.save(on: req)
        }
    }
}
```

Every other method with `req.parameters.next(ModelName.self).flatMap` is also not working inside my digital ocean docker machine.

Something like a simple create works:

```
func create(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Manufacturer> {
    return try req.content.decode(Manufacturer.self).flatMap { manufacturer in
        return manufacturer.save(on: req)
    }
}
```

So i thought there must be something wrong with:

```
return try req.parameters.next(Manufacturer.self).flatMap { manufacturer in
```

The weird part is: when i start the same docker compose configuration on my mac,
everything works as expected - no hung up http request.

I dont know what to do to find the mistake, can somebody help me?
If there is some file which i should provide to solve the problem, please leave a short note and i will update the post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution from the awesome guys in the Vapor Discord Chat: https://discord.gg/BnXmVGA

Thanks to @vzsg and @jimmya92.

The vapor app is running on the smallest digital ocean droplet:

- 1GB memory
- 1vCPU
- 25GB SSD

> there's a known issue that Fluent's default configuration limits the number of connections too much on single core systems
>   which can lead to deadlocks like this
>   drop this in configure.swift to work around it:

```
let poolConfig = DatabaseConnectionPoolConfig(maxConnections: 16)
services.register(poolConfig)
```